# how to update native php 5.3 mac installation with installed brew php 5.4 installation?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I am trying to work on laravel framework, i got an error for which i needed php5.4+. earlier i had installed php, apache and mysql somehow which came with mac.

when i check the versions i get as below:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.19/bin/php -v
PHP 5.4.19 (cli) (built: Sep 17 2013 21:14:22) (DEBUG)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

$ php -v
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

right now php5.3 gets displed on phpinfo(), how to make apache use php5.4?

Answer (score 0):

if `which php` still gives `/usr/bin/php`, add this line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc` if you use ZSH)

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
```

Also see https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php#installing-multiple-versions

**EDIT**
For Apache

`LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php54/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, i added into path and which and -v seem to be updated yet apache is not loading php54. i am not able to find $HOMEBREW_PREFIX/Cellar/php54/5.4.15/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so no folder called libexec? thank you

Comment: hi, thank you for yor reply again. the folder is still not existing in the path. what do i do?

Comment: i installed mamp and it works with php 5.4 and its simple like xampp. laravel also works

Answer (score 0):

php5.3, php5.4, php5.5
http://php-osx.liip.ch/

PHP 5.5
http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/